# Why does moving this ammeter change the polarity of the applied voltage?

Tags: current, components, active-components

**Note:** I'm not an electrical engineer, I'm a materials engineer.  So maybe this question has an obvious answer, but I couldn't find one with a Google search.  I also have no idea if I tagged this properly, sorry!

I was reading through [this open access paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/advs.201801339) on evolvable circuit components and was pretty much following it, right up until the demonstration section at the end.  In the caption to the following figure, the authors note:

> Measuring the current at the terminal where VIn1 is applied, as shown in panel c, causes the current from both inputs to have the same sign.

Why should the ammeter have that effect when it's moved from the position in **a** to the position in **c**?

[image: Schematic and measurements]

(I'm also a bit confused by the final graph in **b**; does the negative current reading here imply that current is flowing back from ground when V2 is applied after training?)

Comment: The resistor has been moved as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, it's been like 5 years since I've studied circuits, i didn't realize those would be electrically different

Comment: V1,V2 are bipolar voltages and currents. But the training correction seems poor

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 By that you mean they have different signs? I know, but what would they then have the same sign after the change in **c**?

Comment: I assume the voltages were low impedance and constant voltage

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The voltages can probably be considered constant (the pulses were 5s long for this part of the study). They said there were some pretty significant double-layer capacitance effects on the electrodes, but at an essentially constant voltage the electrode impedance should be quite low, if I remember correctly how impedance works.

Comment: Yes then voltage polarity changes defines node change in direction of current to ground as this looks like a some ground bias 22k. Cct a) and c) are quite different